# Swift3 use the segue, if want two data type

Tags: swift3, segue

```
use the segue.  view A is two data to the view B, in the view B show two type data. one is a point. like: 75. the two is some words.like: "that's cool. you get that, good job!" 


@IBAction func nextPart(_ sender: UIButton) {

    performSegue(withIdentifier: "aSegueB", sender: myPoint)
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "aSegueB", sender: myText)
    }


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any!) {
    if segue.identifier == "aSegueB"{
        if let two = segue.destination as? twoView{
        two.oneViewNumber = sender as! Int!
         two.oneViewText = sender as! String!
        }
    }
}
```

Use the segue. I use the one type date is ok. But, if I use the two date type, it is broken. Tell me why? How to do that? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Calling `performSegue(withIdentifier` twice to send two parameters will never work. But since the type of `sender` is `Any`, you can also send an array.

By the way, your signature of `prepare(for segue` is wrong, the `sender` is standard optional (`?`)

```
@IBAction func nextPart(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let parameters : [Any] = [myPoint, myText]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "aSegueB", sender: parameters)
}


override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "aSegueB", let two = segue.destination as? twoView {
        two.oneViewNumber = sender[0] as! Int
        two.oneViewText = sender[1] as! String
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much. use your idea, now it's work !!   my app working!! thanks!!